# Find Path of the file using substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have list of file path stored in a column of a table. Now I need to extract only till last '\' in file path (i.e like below result set)
Example:

```
column_A
--------------
G:\REPORTS\DDMS\PCP0.txt
G:\REPORTS\DPS\DEFAU.pdf
```

Result

```
G:\REPORTS\DDMS\
G:\REPORTS\DPS\
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(500)='G:\REPORTS\DDMS\PCP0.txt'

SELECT Reverse(Substring(Reverse(@str), Charindex('\', Reverse(@str)), Len(@str)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with .net , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx Path.GetFileName will parse that for you.

Comment: .Net is available in SQL Server and this kind or processing is arguably done best in SQLCLR.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(500)='G:\REPORTS\DDMS\PCP0.txt'

SELECT LEFT(@str, len(@str) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@str)))
```